# Why would visual studio both work and give errors for a c++ database program that seems otherwise stable?

Tags: c++, mysql

I decided on testing a program before i submit it for a database related assignment. Im supposed to create a system that manages a table of employees, taking various inputs and applying them to a database.

During development, i made sure that each input worked multiple times. Initial testing, it worked each and every time the program was run. I was able to add a user with an id of 1010 (not in the system yet. If the ID was present already, then the system discards the information and informs the user), and then made a nonsense user, and it worked.

I returned to the program to add some final edits such as proper displaying of output, better formatting, etc and just general cleanup and comments, when i noticed that on running the application and trying the same functions out, the program displayed some weird behaviour.

1. On first run, the program detected all employee Id's that i entered (even nonsense ones like 99999) as already existing. When i exited and returned to the program, this ID was suddenly accepted as though nothing happened
2. When i managed to enter a user successfully into the database, it proceeded to immediately autoquit the program (the selection of functions is done via switch/case statement).
3. After 2. occurred, i tried to re-run the program, only for it to repeatedly take the "name" input, and then skip every other input and quit the program immediately. No error message, nothing
4. when i tried to revert all my changes, it continued occurring, even on the most stable build that i had made a few days ago, and then suddenly repeated this behaviour all over again.

Im not entirely sure what i've done wrong to cause it to do this. Is this a common occurrence in VS?

For reference my code is below

this is the code for case 3, the one that deals with entry

```
        case 3:
            cout << "Please Enter the employee number of the employee to add" << endl;
            cin >> empNum;
            failsafe = findEmployee(conn, empNum, emp);
            if (failsafe == 1) {
                if (emp.empNum == 0) {

                    cout << "Employee does not exist or is not in our records. Entry can proceed" << endl;
                    cout << "proceeding with entry" << endl;
                    cout << "-------------" << endl;
                    cout << "Enter the employee's Number: ";
                    cin >> emp.empNum;
                    cin.ignore();
                    cout << "Enter the employee's first name: ";
                    cin >> emp.firstName;
                    cout << "Last name: ";
                    cin >> emp.lastName;
                    cout << "Enter Employee Email: ";
                    cin >> emp.email;
                    cout << "Enter Employee's Extension: ";
                    cin >> emp.extension;
                    cout << "Enter the employee number of the person this employee reports to: ";
                    cin >> emp.reportsTo;
                    cout << "What is this employees' current position? ";
                    cin >> emp.jobTitle;
                    cout << "What city is this employee working within? ";
                    cin >> emp.city;
                    cout << "Compiling employee data" << endl;
                    insertEmployee(conn, emp);

                }
                else {
                    cout << empNum;
                    cout << "An employee with the same number exists." << endl;
                }
            }
            else if (failsafe == 0) {
            cout << "Judging from the way this program reads data, you shouldn't be able to see this"<<endl; //In case the function for some reason *doesnt* return a 1 like it's been doing every time
            }
            break;
```

and heres the code dealing with adding the employee to the database

```
    void insertEmployee(MYSQL* conn, struct Employee& emp) {
        int queResult;
        MYSQL_RES* res;
        cout << "This and the below line is just here for testing to see what exactly it's skipping over" << endl;
        pause();
        if (conn) {
            string query = ("INSERT INTO schoolschema.employees(employeeNumber, lastName, firstName, extension, email, officeCode, reportsTo, jobTitle)"
                " VALUES (" + std::string(" \' " ) + to_string(emp.empNum)  + std::string(" \' ") + " , " + " \' " + emp.lastName + " \' " + " , " + " \' " + emp.firstName + " \' " + " , " + std::string(" \' ") + emp.extension + " \' " + " , " + " \' " + emp.email + " \' " + " , " + to_string(1) + " , " + std::string(" \' ") + emp.reportsTo + " \' "+ " , " + " \' " + emp.jobTitle + " \' " + ");");
            const char* q = query.c_str();
            queResult = mysql_query(conn, q);
            if (!queResult) {
                cout << "Employee successfully added, check to verify by checking the number of the employee from the main menu, or using your DBMS application" << endl;
                return;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Error occurred: " << mysql_errno(conn) << " " << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

and yes im aware the whole

> +" \' "+

thing is kind of ugly but it was a workaround for another issue i was having.

I can post further code snippets if anyone thinks the error might lie elsewhere.

As an added note, i dont believe the problem lies in "find employee" because this function seems to be returning information properly, its just that the compiler seems to be picking and choosing if this data is correct or not. 
(below you can see that im able to delete the user 1010 but i cannot add it back)

the error occurring

```
********************* HR Menu *********************
1)  Find Employee
2)  Employees Report
3)  Add Employee
4)  Update Employee
5)  Remove Employee
0)  Exit
5
Enter employee number to delete: 1010
Employee found, deleting
Employee successfully deleted
********************* HR Menu *********************
1)  Find Employee
2)  Employees Report
3)  Add Employee
4)  Update Employee
5)  Remove Employee
0)  Exit
3
Please enter number to add
1010
employee does not exist, proceeding with entry
Enter Employee number: 1010
Last name: Enter Employee Email: Enter Employee's Extension: Enter the employee number of the person this employee reports to: What is this employees' current position? What city is this employee working within? Compiling employee data
Press enter to continue...
```

***Edit: added note: after the above error appears (the thing that says press enter to continue), it displays a sql error for a bit before immediately assuming that the user has entered "0" and quitting***

Comment: If your program is misbehaviing it's not the fault of VS, it's because the code is wrong. This is normal when you write bad code with any compiler.

Comment: Im not sure if that really helps solve the problem of why it still manages to work some of the time but breaks the rest of the time

Comment: Can you paste your output as text.  The image is difficult to read, especially on mobile phones.  Edit your post with the text.

Comment: apologies one second let me fix that

Comment: Another possibility (common for beginners) is that you aren't operating your compiler correctly.

Comment: Code that only works some of the time is normal for buggy code. There's nothing in C++ that says a bad program must fail predictably or even fail at all.

Comment: There's nothing in the code posted that strikes me as wrong (but very little has been posted). It's tricky debugging code which has unpredictable behaviour, but it's something every programmer has to do from time to time.

Comment: The code you've posted is very straightforward and reasonably well written. It's unlikely to be the bad code. To make progress you need to look over your code with a more critical eye. Some part of your code must be more complicated than simple input and output. That's likely where the error is.

Comment: Yeah, i worked out that the original error, it skipping chunks of functions, was just because i was inputting the wrong thing into an int variable. What doesnt end up being explained is why it seemed to lock up a few times after my usual example user was entered. Even when i made sure in both workbench and the app that user "1010" is gone, it still refused to accept 1010 as a new user...maybe i just have to look at how im validating it

Comment: What is `emp` (in your first code block), is it properly constructed/initialized, and what does `findEmployee` look like?